# How to change the z-index in c#?

Tags: c#, z-index

I have a rich text box that covers the entire form. Under that text box, I have a button, the problem is I need that button to be on top of the text box, so that I can click it. I did some research, and I think I have to change the z-index of the button, but I don't know how to change that. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: is this windows forms?

Comment: So you have a button that is on top of a textbox? Why exactly do you need to do that? What if the button covers the text in the textbox? You should just put the button under the textbox, if possible.

Comment: Yes it was a windows form, and the idea was that the button would be a continue onto the next page of text

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on the Text Box and click Send to back. Or alternatively, focus the button and click Bring to front.

Have a look at [Introduction to Visual Studio .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973867.aspx) and more specifically at

**Table 9. Order options under the Format menu**

I might however recomend that you rather look at using [SplitContainer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx).

> Represents a control consisting of a movable bar that divides a
>   container's display area into two resizable panels.

Have a look at [Windows Forms Controls Lesson 8: How to use the SplitContainer control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb798031.aspx)

Comment: Weird, what ended up working was I added the line:

Button.BringToFront();

When I did the right click, bring to front, it didn't fix the problem, nor did the z-index thing (though I don't think I did that one right). 

Either way, never would have thought to do that, so thank you very much